# How do I write this JOIN query? There is no common table data

Tags: mysql, sql, management-studio-express

I need to display the first and last names of people who have sold items at a price of over $20, I need to join the title and author table but they do not have any common keys? How do I go about doing this? I only need to display their names as input, here's what I have so far and I am getting blank results. I'm just learning, so try not to get too technical

Here are the column names:

```
authors: pk- au_id
             au_fname
             au_lname
titles: pk- title_id
            title   
            price
        fk- pub_id
```

This is what I have so far:

```
select price, au_lname, au_fname
from titles JOIN authors
on authors.au_id=titles.pub_id
```

Comment: you probably have another table that links both author's and book's since a book can have many author's and an author can write several book.

Try to find which table is this one and make authos's JOIN this table JOIN books.

Comment: As Julio say, with current information you **CAN'T** do that query

Comment: I don't have a table called books. My other table names are: authors, discounts, employee, job, pub_info, publishers, roysched, sales, stores, titleauthor.

Comment: The `titleauthor` table has what you need.

Comment: I did find that the titleauthor table has the au_id primary key, but how do I include the price from the titles table?

Comment: The titleauthor table will also have a title_id field.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you also have a `titleauthor` table. That would help with the query in your sample code. However, this table is not needed in this case, as your question is really asking about the **sales person**, rather than the author. You really want something like this:

```
select distinct e.firstname, e.lastname
from sales s
inner join employee e on e.empl_id = s.empl_id
where s.itemprice >= 20
```

Of course, I had to make wild guesses about your column names here. You can extend this to include information about the title and author(s) of those items like so:

```
select distinct e.firstname as SalePersonFirstName, e.lastname as SalesPersonLastName
    , t.Title, a.Lastname As AuthorLastName, a.firstname as FirstName
    , s.itemprice
from sales s
inner join employee e on e.empl_id = s.empl_id
inner join titles t on t.title_id = sales.title_id
inner join titleauthors ta on ta.title_id = t.title_id
inner join authors a on a.au_id = ta.au_id
where s.itemprice >= 20
```

Comment: Here is a better explination of all column names:
Authors:
 au_id
 au_lname
 au_fname
Discounts:
 discounttype 
 stor_id
Employee:
 emp_id
 job_id
 pub_id
 fname
Pub_info:
 pub_id
 logo
Publishers:
 pub_id
 pub_name
Sales
 stor_id
 ord_numb
 title_id
Titleauthor:
 au_id
 title_id
 au_ord
Titles:
 title_id
 pub_id
 price